# Binary Search with insertion point - Why is the insertion point wrong?

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for your time!
I have the following JS code implementing a simple binary search algorithm:

```
function binarySearch( arrayWhereSearching , searchElement , comparePropertyOfArrayWhereSearching , comparePropertyOfSearchElement )
{
    var minIndex = 0 ;
    var maxIndex = arrayWhereSearching.length - 1 ;
    var currentIndex ;
    var currentElement ;

    while( minIndex <= maxIndex )
    {
        currentIndex = ( minIndex + maxIndex ) / 2 | 0 ;
        currentElement = arrayWhereSearching[currentIndex] ;

        if( currentElement[comparePropertyOfArrayWhereSearching] < searchElement[comparePropertyOfSearchElement] )
        {
            minIndex = currentIndex + 1 ;
        }
        else if( currentElement[comparePropertyOfArrayWhereSearching] > searchElement[comparePropertyOfSearchElement] )
        {
            maxIndex = currentIndex - 1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            return currentIndex ;
        }
    }

    return ~currentIndex ;
}
```

If, for example, I test the algorithm to see if I'm getting the insertion point in 2's complement whenever a value is not into an array, I get wrong values.
For example:

```
var ar = [ {value: 1} , {value: 2} , {value: 5} , {value: 9} , {value: 11} , {value: 13}] ;

binaryIndexOfSafehubDevice( ar , {value: 14} , "value" , "value" ) ; // return -6, which 5 in 2's complement. But I was expecting the index 6.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the final return statement to `~minIndex` and it should solve your problem.

`currentIndex` has no information about whether or not the element would come after or before that index. However, `minIndex` will increase if the search element is greater and stay the same if the element is lesser.

Comment: Why use bitwise NOT?

Comment: It's so afterwards you can simply check `currentIndex < 0` to see if it found the element. Otherwise, it can ~ (bitwise NOT) it back to find the insertion index. Although you could just as easily just negate it.

Comment: Clarification, negating doesn't work because of 0. But bitwise OR respects the property ~x < x for all x >= 0, allowing you to store the negated insertion position and check the success of the algorithm with just 1 return value.

Comment: That solved my issue. Thank you Steven! Appreciate it!!